# VPC flow logs: how much vpc flow logs cost?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have egress cost in my gcp project to debug the reason i enabled vpc flow logs for a day .But for just one day it gave me 850gb of logs and also costing arond 300plus USD which is as equal to egress .instead of reducing cost Debugging process increased my total cost ,what should i do with these logs and price .

Answer (score 1):

I can feel for your situation. VPC flow logs cost $0.50 per GB for the first 10 TB. For 850 GB this is $425.00.

In regards to what should you do with the logs, analyze them. They are your log files.

In regards to pricing, either pay the bill or ask Google support to review your situation. Stack Overflow cannot help you with vendor specific issues regarding pricing. Open a support ticket with Google Support. I understand that Google Cloud pays attention to Stack Overflow. Someone might reach out to you, but open that ticket first so that they can.

In hindsight, always read the documentation, understand the services and be knowledgeable about pricing and costs (and add security to this list).

Comment: thanks ,i have raised a ticket .but cost will be applicable.We'll have to pay for it

Comment: For a more precise pricing calculation please refer to [this calculation tool](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/).